# Zend query for "select a table and insert into another with where clause"?

Tags: php, zend-framework

This query is running on MySql Workbench now I need this in Zend.

```
INSERT new_table SELECT * from old_table WHERE date(created_time) < 2015-04-05;
```

Comment: Have a look at this question for example sql... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202376/zend-db-mysql-insert-with-select

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is just use the `query` method of your adapter.

```
// $db is your DB adapter, e.g. an instance of Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli
$db->query('INSERT new_table SELECT * from old_table WHERE date(created_time) < 2015-04-05');
```